# How to include figures using Pythontex

Tags: pythontex, matplotlib

I try the solution of G.Poore (https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/wiki/matplotlib) in order to include easily a lot of figures in a TeX document using Pythontex.

Unfortunately I get the following error and I am not able to fix it.

```
----  Messages for pylab:default:default  ----
  Traceback (most recent call last):
* PythonTeX stderr - error on line 18:
    File "<outputdir>/pylab_default_default.py", line 69, in <module>
      name = savefig()
    File "/Users/.../python_preambule.py", line 17, in savefig
      name = 'auto_fig_{}-{}'.format(pytex.id, fig_count)
  NameError: name 'pytex' is not defined
```

MVE :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pythontexcustomcode}[begin]{pylab}    
sys.path.append('/Users/.../preambulepython/')
from python_preamble import *
\end{pythontexcustomcode}

\begin{document}



\begin{pylabcode}
x = linspace(0, pi)
plt.plot(x, sin(x), label='sin(x)')
plt.plot(x, cos(x), label='cos(x)')
name = savefig()
fig = latex_figure(name)
\end{pylabcode}
\pylab{fig}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the python_preamble.sty file? Also, the pythontexcusomcode is supposed to be in the preamble as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey for your suggestion. I have just specified the complete path, and I put `pythontexcusomcode` in the preamble (I have edited my question). The error changed in `bad magic number in 'python_preamble`.

Comment: If I insert directly the code of `python_preamble` in the tex preamble (without using a python importation), I get the error `Illegal parameter number in definition of \pytx@type`.

Comment: Perhaps you version of pythontex is outdated?

Comment: The package is updated. The error is still `File "/Users/.../python_preambule.py", line 17, in savefig
      name = 'auto_fig_{}-{}'.format(pytex.id, fig_count)
  NameError: name 'pytex' is not defined`

Comment: Try changing `name = savefig()` to `name = savefig(name="newfigurename")`. Alternatively, recode the one line as `name = 'auto_fig_{}'.format(fig_count)`.

Comment: I tried the both solutions, thank you. The common error is now : `File "/Users/.../python_preambule.py", line 25, in savefig
      fig = gcf()
  NameError: name 'gcf' is not defined`

Comment: At this point, you should download, compile, and work with the examples given at the [pythontex GitHub](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex). When they do not compile, something is wrong with your python+LaTex installation. I suspect the problem is with the python installation rather than with the LaTeX installation. You can troubleshoot further perhaps by running the python code in a Jupyter notebook. Does it work? Until it does, you cannot hope to have it work in LaTeX. Once the examples are compiled to run, one or the other of them can be modified to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Are you still having issues with this?  Because I noticed a couple issues that haven't been addressed here.  First, you need `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your `.tex` file (to use `\includegraphics`.  Second, in that `python_preamble.py` file, there are a bunch of `\\\\ ` which actually should just be `\\ `.  I get errors (such as `^^@:3: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`) when using `\\\\ ` because those translate into LaTeX as `\\begin` etc. instead of `\begin` etc., which you need.  (For the `NameError: name 'gcf' is not defined`, try using `plt.gcf()` instead?)

Comment: Thank you whatisit ! all is working fine now.